# Difference between authpriv and auth?

Tags: syslog

What's the difference between authpriv and auth in syslog configuration?

It wasn't mentioned in syslog.conf, only tells me that such facility exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`authpriv` – non-system authorization messages

`auth`-authentication and authorization related commands

earlier `LOG_AUTHPRIV` is for hiding sensitive log messages inside a protected
file, e.g., /var/log/auth.log. whereas `LOG_AUTH` on Linux is not configured with restricted access normally,whereas `LOG_AUTHPRIV` is.
`LOG_AUTH` instead of using something generic like `LOG_USER`.

It is recommended to use `LOG_AUTHPRIV` for auth logs that have a substantial risk of recording someone's password

The GNU C Library manual doesn't document `LOG_AUTHPRIV` at all and just has
`LOG_AUTH`, so the Linux manpages aren't getting it from there.

now from `man syslog` i got `LOG_AUTH       security/authorization    messages    (DEPRECATED    Use LOG_AUTHPRIV instead)`

but most of the code i have seen has something like

```
 #ifndef LOG_AUTHPRIV
 #define LOG_AUTHPRIV LOG_AUTH
 #endif`
```

so it is upto you to decide which one to use

Answer (score 3):

authpriv is a separate bucket for routing authorization messages to a log file that has more restricted permissions that those of auth.  Different OS's will send different messages to auth vs. authpriv.